# Password creation link which was sent to the mail could not redirect the proper page in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I can mail password creation link to the email address. But when I click that link it doesn't open my "Password Creation Page", instead it goes to my home page.

My route is:

```
Route::get('auth/set/password/{token}', 'Auth\PasswordController@getSetPassword')
```

any my PasswordController page is:

```
public function getSetPassword($token)
{
   return view('auth.create_password');
}
```

and the link in my mail is:

```
Click the given below link to generate your password:
http://krankontroll:8000/auth/set/password/IhQTMgArKUNYPf18WoloHzhWIjlewt
```

When I click this link it redirects to,

```
http://krankontroll:8000/home
```

What mistake I made here? Can anyone help me with this????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you making sure there isn't some filter redirecting you? This could either be in your routes file, or in your controller. And also, make sure you are not already authenticated, most login systems won't allow you to reset your password, if you are already logged in.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Once I logged out and clicked the link it shows the password creation page.... thanks...